# Loop a Console.ReadLine in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, loops

I am writing a simple pay estimation calculator in Visual Studio Express 2013 and have gotten most of the code typed up. However, one of the major hurdles I am trying to overcome is the looping of the entry point until the user enters something for it [the program] to process. Now, if I am not mistaken, this will have to be a two in one operation.

- Key Validation so that only numbers are accepted
  and
- The loop itself

I have been trying to implement certain things and to some degree they work but in the end the fail and all comes back to an inability of the program to convert one to another or from something to something else.

The Code I need to loop is seven sections. Full section example is;

```
Console.Clear()
Console.WriteLine("")
Console.WriteLine("Minute Entry for MONDAY.")
Console.WriteLine("")
Console.WriteLine("════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════")
Console.WriteLine("Enter number then press ENTER to continue...")
Console.WriteLine("")
MonMin = Console.ReadLine()
```

Comment: can you please be more specific as for what your problem is?

Comment: The code I need to loop is posted above. I am vaguely aware how loops work but in this instance, I am not sure what to do. The idea is to loop until a number is entered. Say, if someone tries to skip past without entering anything I need it to loop back with a reminder to enter something. On another note, if they were to enter letter or characters it would say that those characters are invalid.

Comment: I think that you are asking for too much. If you are not even used to write loops, you are not asking to solve a punctual problem (because you have the minimal understanding); you are asking someone to write a full-working code for you (what SO is not about). It seems that you need to learn better the basics before coming into more difficult problems (e.g., analysing the user inputs, moving the cursor, etc.)

Comment: I second @varocarbas, did you try getting your loops knowledge first and try it? not sure how giving you working code will do you any good.

Comment: Okay. I believe I may have misunderstood to purpose of SO - I will head off and try to gain a better understanding of what I am attempting to do. If I still can't comprehend it then, well, I may have bitten off more than I can chew.

For what it is worth I wasn't asking for full-working code, but simply a little help in which direction to head to get the problem solved.

Comment: Loops are one of the basic bits in programming (in any language). If you want to learn programming you have to understand this (and equivalent bits perfectly). SO is for programmers who, at least, have a minimal understanding of the given problem and thus the kind of help delivered here is of use for knowledgeable people. For example, the Nico Schertler's answer is pretty down to basics, but even though is not a code you can directly execute; not even a valuable knowledge without a minimal understanding. The best way to learn is doing things by your own (and ask only if no other way).

Answer (score 0):

If you need seven sections, it should be clear that you need a for loop that loops seven times:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To 6

Next
```

At the beginning of this loop print your introductory text. You can use an array to map `i` to a day (e.g. `Console.WriteLine("Minute Entry for " & days(i)))`.

As you already mentioned, the `ReadLine` has to be encapsulated within another loop that does the validation:

```
Dim validEntry = False
While Not validEntry
    MonMin = Console.ReadLine()
    'Do the validation
End While
```

The validation has to check for numerical inputs. E.g.

```
If IsNumeric(MonMin) Then validEntry = True
```

If you want to print an error message, you can use a second variable that stores if the loop runs for the first time:

```
Dim firstTime = True
While Not validEntry
    If Not firstTime Then Console.WriteLine("The entered value is not valid")
    firstTime = False
    'Go on ...
End While
```

You may want to save `MonMin` to an array once it is validated.